# running code when two events have triggered

Tags: javascript, events, language-agnostic

This is mostly a language-agnostic question.

If I'm waiting for two events to complete (say, two IO events or http requests), what is the best pattern to deal with this. One thing I can think of is the following (pseudo js example).

```
request1.onComplete = function() {
  req1Completed = true;
  eventsCompleted();
}

request2.onComplete = function() {
  req2Completed = true;
  eventsCompleted();
}

eventsCompleted = function() {

  if (!req1Completed || !req2Completed) return;
  // do stuff

}
```

Is this the most effective pattern, or are there more elegant ways to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you expecting these events to occur in a particular order? That affects the solution greatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before even going into the details, here's something neat that takes advantage of lambda functions off the top of my head:

```
function makeCountdownCallback(count, callback) {
    return function() {
        if (--count == 0)
            callback();
    };
}

request1.onComplete = request2.onComplete = makeCountdownCallback(2, function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

This obviously assumes that each event fires at most once, and doesn't take advantage of order.

Comment: This solution is better if you have an arbitrary number of events that you're waiting on, but the fact that it only works if the events occur *once* is a bit dangerous.

Comment: That's kinda slick.  A little crazy, but slick.

Comment: Not a bad solution; This one wins, although part of me does feel this is a bit of a dirty solution :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 1.5 has Deferreds: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

You can easily set them up to call back only when some events have been triggered.

Comment: A "deferred" is definitely something to look into. It allows you to make a pretty neat interface to track multiple callbacks, something along the lines of `afterAllOfThese(def1, def2, def2, function() { ... })`... unless of course jQuery already has something for waiting for multiple events.

Comment: I am hoping for a generic solution, applicable to multiple languages.

Answer (score 1):

**Try #1**: Here's a solution that doesn't require additional global variables:

```
request1.onComplete = function() {
    // register new handler for event2 here, overwriting the old one
    request2.onComplete = function() {
        // now they're both done
    }
}

request2.onComplete = function() {
    // register new handler for event1 here, overwriting the old one
    request1.onComplete = function() {
        // now they're both done
    }  
}
```

The handler for whichever event fires first will clear the other's old handler and assign a new one that includes the stuff you need to do after the completion of both events. Because we re-assign the second handler inside the handler of the first event (whichever that is), we always know we're done when that second handler finishes.

**Try #2**: Here's something that will work if each event type is different:

```
function onBoth(fn) {
    var last, done = false;
    return function(e) {
        if (last && last !== e.type && !done) {
            fn(); // done
            done = true;
        }
        last = e.type;
    }
}
```

For example, this won't alert "done" until the user has both scrolled and clicked:

```
var both = onBoth(function() {
    alert("done")
});

document.addEventListener("scroll", both, false);
document.addEventListener("click", both, false);
```

**Try #3**: The previous try can be modified to work for similar events:

```
function onBoth(fn) {
    var last, done = false;
    return function(curr) {
        if (last && last !== curr && !done) {
            fn(); // done
            done = true;
        }
        last = curr;
    }
}
```

...which should be used like this:

```
var check = onBoth(function() {
    alert("done")
});

request1.onComplete = function() {
    check(arguments.callee);
}

request2.onComplete = function() {
    check(arguments.callee);
}
```

Basically, this checks that two different callbacks have executed by storing a reference to the most recently executed call back. Its usage is a little clunky, but it gets the job done (i.e. it will still work if each of the events executes more than once).

Comment: `request1` and `request2` look quite global to me

Comment: @Matti - Of course they are. Clearly I meant that it doesn't require additional global flags to indicate that each handler has finished.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it: http://tobireif.com/posts/waiting_for_two_events/

```
Q.spread([
  getA(), getB()
], function(a, b) {
  // Use the results a and b.
// Catch errors:
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Minimal for this example:
  console.log(error);
});
```

The lib is at https://github.com/kriskowal/q .